# Putting 2 tables side by side

Tags: tables, spacing

There are a few of the same questions for what I am about to ask but they do not help me for what I want to in Latex.

I want to put 2 tables side by side, and have small captions above them, as they are small, but I cannot seem to do it even with `\userpackage{subfig}`.

Also some tables are appearing at end of page, when I am writing text below them! Very frustrating.

This is code

```
\begin{table}[]

 \caption{q =3}
 \begin{tabular}{1|2|3|r}
 \hline
    n  & 1 & 2 & 3  \\
    \hline
    $\chi_1(n)$ & 1 & 1 & 0\\
    $\chi_2(n)$  & 1 & -1 & 0\\
 \end{tabular}
\quad


\end{table}\\

\begin{table}[]

 \caption{q = 4}
 \begin{tabular}{1|2|3|4|r}
 \hline
    n  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4  \\
    \hline
    $\chi_1(n)$ & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    $\chi_2(n)$  & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\

 \end{tabular}
 \quad
 \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}\\


\begin{table}[]
 \begin{right}
 \caption{q = 5}
 \begin{tabular}{1|2|3|4|5|r}
    n  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\
    \hline
    $\chi_1(n)$ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
    $\chi_2(n)$  & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
    $\chi_3(n)$ & 1 & $i$ & $-i$ & -1 & 0\\
    $\chi_4(n)$  & 1 & $-i$ & $i$ & -1 & 0\\

 \end{tabular}

 \label{tab:my_label}
 \end{right}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{left}
 \caption{q = 7}
 \begin{tabular}{1|2|3|4|5|6|7}
    n  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
    \hline
    $\chi_1(n)$ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1& 0\\
    $\chi_2(n)$  & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0&0\\
    $\chi_3(n)$ & 1 & $ \omega^2$ & $ \omega $ & $-\omega$ & $-\omega^2$ & -1 & 0\\
    $\chi_4(n)$ & 1 & $\omega^2$ & $-\omega$ & $-\omega$ & $\omega^2$ & 1 & 0\\
    $\chi_5(n)$ & 1 & $-\omega^2$ & $\omega^2$ & $\omega^2$ & $-\omega$ & 1 & 0\\
    $\chi_6(n)$ & 1 & $-\omega$ & $-\omega^2$ & $\omega^2$ & $\omega$ & -1 & 0\\
 \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: the `\\ ` after the `table` is wrong and also using the option of `[]` means the table may not be placed anywhere,  although latex detects that and ignores the option with a warning in that case.   To get the tables side by side simply use two minipage that are .5\textwidth wide.

Comment: Note "Also some tables are appearing at end of page, when I am writing text below them! " that is not surprising, the only reason to use a `table` environment is to specify that the content is a float that may be moved to help with page breaking.

Answer (score 2):

A small variation of @MadyYuvi answer (+1), without use of the `adjustbox` package, used are `makecell` and `caption` packages:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{array, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
    \caption{$q=3$}
    \label{tab:q3}
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{$}l<{$}| *{2}{>{$}r<{$}|} >{$}r<{$}}
    \hline
\makecell{n}    & 1 &  2 & 3    \\
    \hline
\chi_1(n)       & 1 &  1 & 0    \\
\chi_2(n)       & 1 & -1 & 0    
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
    \caption{$q=4$}
    \label{tab:q4}
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{$}l<{$}| *{3}{>{$}r<{$}|} >{$}r<{$}}
    \hline
\makecell{n}    & 1 &  2 & 3 & 4    \\
    \hline
\chi_1(n)       & 1 &  1 & 0 & 0    \\
\chi_2(n)       & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0    
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
To have two tables in parallel, than both had to be in the same float `table` and between them should not be empty lines. This is resolved with suggested MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small but complete document).

The placement of the `table` float depends on the table's placement options (see @David Carlisle's comment). With replacing wrong `[]` with `[ht]` table will appear in the document at point of its insertion in the text, if there is enough space on page or on the top of the next page. Since preamble of your document is unknown to us, we cant further help you.

Comment: You always great

Answer (score 1):

Below code may helps you:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\adjustbox{valign=t}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
 \caption{q =3}
 \begin{tabular}[t]{l|l|l|r}
 \hline
    n  & 1 & 2 & 3  \\
    \hline
    $\chi_1(n)$ & 1 & 1 & 0\\
    $\chi_2(n)$  & 1 & -1 & 0\\
 \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}}\quad
\adjustbox{valign=t}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
 \caption{q = 4}
 \begin{tabular}[t]{l|l|l|l|r}
 \hline
    n  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4  \\
    \hline
    $\chi_1(n)$ & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    $\chi_2(n)$  & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
 \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}}
 \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]